# gradle load jar from plain url as dependency

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I want to load a jar, that is hosted under 'releases' on github as a dependency. This jar does not exist in a repo.

After some research I found that 'faking' a custom ivy repo is the way to go. See here: [How do you handle web hosted .jar-files as dependencies in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678811/how-do-you-handle-web-hosted-jar-files-as-dependencies-in-gradle)

However it does not work. It even says that it is loading the jar file. But then it says it cannot find it.

This is the link where the jar is:

```
https://github.com/criteo-forks/xgboost-jars/releases/download/0.82-criteo-20190412/xgboost4j-0.82-criteo-20190412_2.11-win64.jar
```

```
       ivy {
           url 'https://github.com/'
           patternLayout {
               artifact '[organization]-forks/[module]-jars/releases/download/0.82-criteo-20190412/[revision]'
           }
       }
```

and

```
dependencies{
  compile group:"criteo", name:"xgboost", version:"xgboost4j-0.82-criteo-20190412_2.11-win64.jar"
}
```

(other than in the link given above, I removed the "[ext]", as then it was always searching for a file with extention 'xml')

As said, according to logs, this seems to build the correct url ... but does not download it. The only thing I can think of, that it somehow refuses to take it, as it's not really an Ivy repository.

Any hint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38105112/175554 may help